# mvc mobile web app saving to local device

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

is it possible to save some settings to a device from a mobile mvc app ?? I just have a few items that I would like to save in a very small file, that when they load the webpage it can load these settings from a local location ??

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this one of them being the HTML 5 powered [Webstorage such as localStorage or SessionStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and an other [link - HTML5ROCKS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage)  about webstorage this of course requires the user to have an up to date browser!

Small example:

```
    localStorage.setting ="1";
    document.getElementById("setting").innerHTML="your setting info " + localStorage.setting;
```

. 
 An other way could be to save the settings in a database or a file on your server.
I'm assuming that the latter on will be the one you need.

Comment: thanks for the response, the only reason I want to save it locally, is because there are only 2 or 3 items that I need to save, and I can easily pull these back in when they visit the site.